# What is the exercise regimen under the SPRINT program?

Tags: iss, nasa, medical, health, humans

[NASA](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/Sprint.html) says (emphasis mine)

> **Current exercise countermeasures on the International Space Station (ISS) are insufficient to prevent muscle atrophy, cardiovascular deconditioning and bone loss associated with long-duration space flight**. Despite crew allocation of approximately 2.5 hours per day to exercise, decrements in fitness are observed following flights averaging 180 days in duration. Muscle strength is decreased 11% to 17%, muscular endurance approximately 10% and bone mineral density 2% to 7%.

It is thus that NASA commissioned Sprint also linked in the article above

> Integrated Resistance and Aerobic Training Study (Sprint) evaluates the use of high intensity, low volume exercise training to minimize loss of muscle, bone, and cardiovascular function in ISS crewmembers during long-duration missions.

What is the regimen under the Sprint program?

Answer (score 2):

From the page you linked to:

> The new Integrated Resistance and Aerobic Training Study (Sprint) protocol uses an evidence based approach to develop a higher intensity, lower duration exercise program utilizing ISS exercise hardware: the Advanced Resistance Exercise Device (ARED) and a second generation treadmill, Combined Operational Load Bearing External Resistance Treadmill (COLBERT).

[This presentation](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20100039331.pdf) (PDF, page 9-12) contains details on the exercise regimen.

- Resistance training: 35-60 min every odd day
- Aerobic interval training: varying amounts every even day
- Aerobic continuous training: 30 min every odd day

More details in the PDF.
Note that SPRINT is an [ongoing](https://blogs.nasa.gov/stationreport/2015/06/12/iss-daily-summary-report-061215/) study, not an operational training regimen.