# Have traditional forms of exercise such as Yoga been studied in orbit?

Tags: medical, physical-activity

A follow-up to [What is the exercise regimen under the SPRINT program?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2438/what-is-the-exercise-regimen-under-the-sprint-program)

The [Sprint](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/Sprint.html) program is briefly described as

> Integrated Resistance and Aerobic Training

Now this may just be dogma on my part but it puts me in mind of [Hatha Yoga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatha_yoga). The latter may crudely be described as calisthenics with aerobics often applying muscles to oppose each other.

- What traditional forms of exercise have been studied for the space program, and in orbit? 
  E.g. Yoga, Tai Chi
- Are there any papers specifically on the use of Hatha Yoga aboard ISS or it's predecessors?

Answer (score 7):

This is a part answer about the connection between yoga (in general) and space travel.

A hypothesis about yoga and space travel is discussed in the article [Yoga Therapy as a Complement to Astronaut Health and Emotional Fitness –
Stress Reduction and Countermeasure Effectiveness Before, During, and in
Post-Flight Rehabilitation: a Hypothesis](http://www.yogaforspacehealth.org/downloads/paper4.pdf) (Vernikos et al. 2012), where the basis of their hypothesis is

> yoga practices – breathing maneuvers, relaxation,
>   meditation, and specific muscular movement –
>   may serve this purpose by addressing as a whole,
>   both the effects of microgravity and those of nongravitational
>   stressful conditions, before, during,
>   and in post-flight rehabilitation.

Specifically, by allowing self-directed stress reduction/mitigation techniques (both conscious and unconscious), as well as allowing a quicker and more effective adaptation between the Earth and space environments.

Specifically,

> Our
>   hypothesis acknowledges that stress and the
>   microgravity of space disturb the balance of the
>   adrenocortical, autonomic, and immune systems
>   resulting in a generalized inflammatory response.
>   Our hypotheses also reflect the need for more
>   evidence that yoga practices can be used to restore
>   balance and thereby complement the effectiveness
>   of current CMs used during spaceflight.

This is not the first time that yoga techniques have been considered for space travel, according to the article [A Review: History of Revival of Yoga in 20th Century
and Establishment of Yoga as a Science in the 21st century](http://www.yoga-science.rs/eng/sciarticles2011/12-arun-raghuwanshi.pdf) (Raghuwanshi, 2011), state

> In early sixties Dhirendra Brahmachari (1924 – 1994) propagated yoga researches, with the help of modern medical science,... In late sixties and early seventies he took part in promotion of scientific approach in yoga. **He was asked by the Government of USSR to teach yoga to the astronauts as a technique to adjust and equip to the unknown situations of the space journey.**